# Terrain correction (flattening) of Sentinel 1 images

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

Using the script available in this forum (belowlink), I tried for terrain correction (flattening) of Sentinel 1 images

[Getting local incidence angle from Sentinel-1 GRD image collection in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352602/getting-local-incidence-angle-from-sentinel-1-grd-image-collection-in-google-ear/352658#352658)

Here is my working script.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0a0ae5e730afd766d0c2eb4c4a07c937

Unfortunately, why the resulted gamma0dB is all white?

Could someone look at above link and solve it?

I really want to return terrain corrected (flattened) gamma0dB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate gamma0 like this:

```
function toGamma0(image) {
  var gamma0 = image.expression('i - 10 * log10(cos(angle * pi / 180))', {
    i: image.select(['VV', 'VH']),
    angle: image.select('angle'),
    pi: Math.PI
  })
  return image.addBands(gamma0, null, true)  
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/33e9cffee06f27b92b86e15b713a17cc

Comment: Your problem isn't gamma0 related. The terrain correction script expects images from COPERNICUS/S1_GRD, not COPERNICUS/S1_GRD_FLOAT. I'm curious why you're using the terrain correction script just to return gamma0 without actually doing any terrain correction. In any case, this should work for you:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f7aa86f93f119c3c7f89c0e2668fdfe1

Comment: What was returned in the original terrain correction function you linked to in your question.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6c3fcaa8fbaff069c46389128b2ffc7c

Comment: select(['VV', 'VH', 'slope_1', 'slope_2'], ['VV', 'VH', 'layover', 'shadow']) selects 4 bands, 'VV', 'VH', 'slope_1', 'slope_2', and renames them to 'VV', 'VH', 'layover', 'shadow'. Btw, you might want to layover and shadow to mask your image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105720/discussion-between-mk1-and-daniel).